# Angular 12 upgrade error: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, angular12

I have upgraded from Angular 11 to 12 getting below error for many of my angular components.

```
./src/app/virtualspaces/home/home.component.html:1:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

./src/app/virtualspaces/home/home.component

```html
<div id="enterVirtualSpaces">
  <div class="bgEls">
    <div class="_bgEl1"></div>
    <div class="_bgEl2"></div>
  </div>
  <header>
    <div class="null1"><a class="logo" href="/enter"></a></div>
  </header>
  <div class="maincontent">
    <h2>Enter</h2>
    <a href="/enter/meetings">Meetings</a>
    <a href="/enter/conferences">Conferences</a>
    <a href="/enter/xpos">Expos</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know Angular discontinued the use of webpack from Angular 10 but I tried experimenting with installing webpack with `npm i -D @expo/webpack-config` and adding a webpack.config.js file at the root and adding this code:

```js
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require('@expo/webpack-config');

module.exports = async function(env, argv) {
    const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync({
        ...env,
        babel: {
            dangerouslyAddModulePathsToTranspile: ['@ui-kitten/components']
        }
    }, argv);
    return config;
};
```

It didn't work.

I'll like to understand why the problem and possible ways to fix it as many components that were working fine in my Angular 11 project are showing errors and not allowing the project to compile again.

**UPDATE 1**

Using **ng g c componentPath** to generate a new file. The new file is immediately added to the files throwing the error.

I loaded dynamic components in some of the components that are not even related to the files throwing errors. Can this be a possible source?

Also, I created a fresh angular 12 project and gradually updated the files to see if I get errors.

Initially I don't get errors for newly generated components until I copy my components folder over. Every component was generated using angular cli except dynamic components which are dynamically imported.

Here's one of my typescript files importing a component dynamically

post-box3.component.ts

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Input,
  Output,
  Renderer2,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef,
  ViewContainerRef,
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-post-box3",
  templateUrl: "./post-box3.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./post-box3.component.scss"],
})
export class PostBox3Component implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("postContent", { read: ViewContainerRef }) postContentEl!: ViewContainerRef;
  constructor(
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private vcRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private elmRef: ElementRef
  ) {
    this.dynLoadBIComp();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  async dynLoadBIComp({ 
    const compObj: any = await import(
      "../../../../templates/logo/1/logo1b/logo1b.component"
    );

    const compKeys: any = Object.keys(compObj);    
    this.postContentEl.createComponent(
      this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(compObj[compKeys[0]])
    );;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just also hit this problem -- trying to "vendor" a 3rd party package into my existing angular project.  Did you ever find what the problem was?

Answer (score 2):

How is your `html` loaded into the application? I am going to assume that it is *not* a template. We had this problem when we loaded files (in our case, image) through `require`. For example, the problematic statement was

```
photopath = somepath ? somepath : require('../assets/image-not-found.png');
```

That threw same exception as yours - compiler expected JavaScript code and `<` was unexpected token. We replaced `require` with simply `'../assets/image-not-found.png'` and it solved the problem. So, back to my first question - how do you load your html?

Comment: I basically created a component 'ng g c componentPath' . Can this error occur if I dynamically load a component in another file but in the same directory? Cos I did load components dynamically in some files that are not even related to the files showing up in the error. Now if  I just generate any component, they are included in the errors. This was not so in Angular 11

Comment: yes, that's what we had as well... the *dynamic* loading became much more difficult

Comment: Ok should I not load components dynamically again? Or what's the workaround loading dynamic components and not having these almost untraceable errors? It's complaining about almost every html in the project. Or should I just downgrade back to Angular 11?

Comment: can you show *how* you are loading? You say *dynamically*, but it may mean a lot of things. We load HTML as templates, so it was never an issue. Alternatively, you can load HTML into the TypeScript variable, and bind it to the template. And ultimately, yes - we were not able to find a way to dynamically load files from the code. there are some explanations why it is by design, and why it is better, and more secure - so you better get on with the program, or you will be stuck on Angular 11

Comment: UPDATE: I see `import()` - yes won't work. There is an alternative to use Angular elements https://angular.io/guide/elements but for simple situations (like, if the name of the component is a constant in your case), you may want to to make it part of the template instead of .ts file